# Return the first n elements of an array in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

What is the best way to return the first n elements of an array in Coffeescript? If there are fewer than n elements in the array, then array should be returned unchanged. These are the two solutions I came up with:

With a for loop and break:

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
n = 3
firstn = []
for i in [0..n-1]
  if arr[i]
    firstn.push(arr[i])
  else
    break
```

With a list comprehension

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
n = 3
firstn = (arr[i] for i in [0..n-1] when arr[i])
```

Both of these will work, however neither is very clean. The first is not very clear at first glance. The second is slightly better but it iterates over the whole array unnecessarily and looks up the value twice for each element in the output. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array slicing (http://coffeescript.org/#language)

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

arr[..2]
```

works as you want if there are fewer than n element in the array (just returns the whole array)